# Controller Tests using Jasmine and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I am getting the following error

```
Expected 0 to be 4.
    ...anggen/app/products/products.list.controller.spec.js:22:35
```

Could anyone tell me why the httpbackend is not returning the response? or is it something silly that I missed? Spent a lot of time on getting this to work and am stuck..
Please look at the test case below. The test in question is it("should create controller"... test
My controller code is as follows...

```
module app.productList {
  'use strict';

  export interface IProductListModel {
    title: string;
    showImage: Boolean;
    products: app.domain.IProduct[];
    toggleImage(): void;
    addNumbers(firstNumber:number, secondNumber:number): number;
  }

  export class ProductListCtrl implements IProductListModel {

    title:string;
    showImage:boolean;
    products:app.domain.IProduct[];

    static $inject = ["dataAccessService"];  // for minification
    constructor(private dataAccessService:app.productService.DataAccessService) {
      this.title = "Product List";
      this.showImage = false;
      this.products = [];
      dataAccessService.getProductResource().query((data:app.domain.IProduct[]) => {
        this.products = data;
      });
    }

    public toggleImage():void {
      this.showImage = !this.showImage;
    }

    public addNumbers(firstNumber:number, secondNumber:number) {
      return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }

  }

  angular.module("app.products").controller("ProductListCtrl", ProductListCtrl)
}
```

My service code is as follows...

```
module app.productService {
  export interface IDataAccessService {
    getProductResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource>;
    getProductResourceDetails(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource>;
  }

  export interface IProductResource extends ng.resource.IResource<app.domain.IProduct> {
  }

  export class DataAccessService
    implements IDataAccessService {

    // for minification.
    static $inject = ["$resource"];
    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {

    }

    getProductResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource> {
      //return this.$resource("/api/products/:productId");
      return this.$resource("http://localhost:9998/generic/products");
    }

  }

  angular
    .module("app.products")
    .service("dataAccessService", DataAccessService);
}
```

My Test code is as follows...

```
describe("Product List Controller", function () {

  var controller: app.productList.ProductListCtrl;
  var dataAccessService: app.productService.DataAccessService;
  var $httpBackend : ng.IHttpBackendService;

  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module("productManagement");
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (
    $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,
    _$httpBackend_: ng.IHttpBackendService,
    _dataAccessService_: app.productService.DataAccessService) {
    dataAccessService=_dataAccessService_;
    $httpBackend=_$httpBackend_;
  }));


  it("should create controller", () => {
    $httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:9998/generic/products").respond([
      {"id": "1", "name": "Pizza Vegetaria", "price": 5 },
      {"id": "2", "name": "Pizza Salami",    "price": 5.5 },
      {"id": "3", "name": "Pizza Thunfisch", "price": 6 },
      {"id": "4", "name": "Aktueller Flyer", "price": 0 }
    ]);

    controller = new app.productList.ProductListCtrl(dataAccessService);
    expect(controller).not.toBeNull();

    var result = controller.products;
    expect(result.length).toBe(4);
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });


});
```

Comment: Call `flush` before `expect`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. That worked.